# QWebview not showing on Widget box

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, qwebview, qt5.6

I am using `Qt 5.6`, and the problem is that `QWebView` is not appearing on the widget box. It looks like the widget is not installed, but I haven't found any way to install it.

[image: QWebView issue]

Comment: add it in code then. create some placeholder widget which you later replace by the webview. or you insert it...
Same as you'd do with your custom widgets.

Comment: I am trying to do what you suggested, but the editor is not recognizing the QWebView class. This is how I am including it:
#include "QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView"

Answer (score 1):

In Qt 5.6 You need to use QWebEngineView then you can load your web page in qwidget.

Answer (score 1):

Build-in support of QWebView/QWebKit was removed from Qt 5.6, see details [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6). You still can use them if you will build Qt from sources and include QWebKit.

Or you can port you application to use Qt Web Engine, see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html).